# run create-react-app without installing dependencies

Tags: create-react-app

I'm developing a template for `create-react-app`. To test the template i run

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template file:<path-to-my-template>
```

This also installs all the dependencies in the `node_module` folder, making the whole process quite slow if I make frequent changes.

Is there a way to bootstrap the application without automatically installing the dependencies?

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple; you may create the app and then delete the `node_modules`:

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app
rm -rf node_modules
```